# search for multiple occurrences of substring from string

Tags: r, stringr

Below is my dataset. I am using the function `strdetect()` on the `key` column like so.

`str_detect(mydata$Key, 'R')`

I want to be able to search for strings that contain 2 `R`'s. Obviously in the below example I could just search for `R002R009` but I do not always no the numbers attached to the `R`'s so I just want to search for strings with 2 `R`'s

I need to be able to use it inside an `ifelse` statement

```
 mydata[1:3]
           IDENTIFIER  DATE_TIME         X-VALUE     Y-VALUE      Key
    1      214461707   1/04/2019 8:25           1         -3       A001
    2      214461789   1/04/2019 10:16          1         -2       R001
    3      214461789   1/04/2019 10:16          1         -5       R002R009
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `str_count` to count number of occurrences of a letter and use it in `filter`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

mydata %>% filter(str_count(Key, 'R') == 2)

#   FACILITY_ID      DATE_TIME XVALUE YVALUE      Key
#3   214461789 1/04/201910:16      1     -5 R002R009
```

Comment: I need to be able to use this inside an if else statement

Comment: What do you mean by that? What do you want to check in `ifelse` statement?

Comment: I am using the following code in an `ifelse` statement `str_detect(Key, 'R')` and creating a new column based off if i detect the substring

Comment: Does that make sense?

Comment: No, not really. So if you are using `str_detect(Key, 'R')` in an `ifelse` statement what is the role of counting 2 R's? Also I don't understand creating a new column part. Can you edit your post to show expected output?

Comment: So I want to detect substrings such as `R` and `A`, but I also want to detect when I have two `R`s in a string

Comment: something like this would work? `str_detect(Key, 'R') & str_count(Key, 'R') == 2`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression with str_detect.

```
mydata %>% 
  filter(str_detect(string = Key, pattern = "R.*R"))
```

results in:

```
         id FACILITY_ID DATE_TIME X.VALUE Y.VALUE      Key
3 214461789   1/04/2019     10:16       1      -5 R002R009
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `subset` from `base R`

```
subset(mydata, nchar(gsub('[^R]+', '', Key)) == 2)
```